# Conversion - unwrapping an optional value

Tags: swift

I'm trying to code a **BMI calculator**

```
@IBOutlet var height: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var weight: UITextField!    
@IBOutlet var message: UILabel!    
@IBAction func keyPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var peso = Double(weight.text.toInt()!)
    var altura = Double(height.text.toInt()!) //ERROR LINE
    var alturaquad = Double(peso) * Double(peso)  //EXPONENTIAL
    var imc = altura / alturaquad
    message.text = "Your BMI is \(imc)"
}
```

I'm getting the following error, which I didn't understand yet:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

My second question is about an exponential function. Is it the pow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toInt()` method of `String` returns an optional integer, i.e. a valid integer if the conversion from string to int succeeds, or `nil` if the conversion fails.

Here:

```
height.text.toInt()!
```

you're using the forced unwrapping operator, which unwraps the integer from the optional, making the assumption that it is not nil - and if the optional is actually `nil`, you have that error.

Optionals, forced unwrapping and errors like yours are recurrent questions on stack overflow. I suggest you to carefully read [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496). It's conceptually simple, but source of many headaches - a comprehensive understanding of how they works is essential for any swift developer. Hint: use optional binding to solve your problem.

As for your 2nd question, about `pow`: have you tried that? Create a playground and test it - then ask a new question if it doesn't work.